# Do comet orbits lie in the same plane as the other planets?

Tags: planet, orbit, comets

Two typical comets that I know are Donati's and Halley's. So comets also have orbits, but are their orbits on the same plane (such as the ecliptic) as the other planets?

Comment: Answered in the section on orbital characteristics in https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet

Answer (score 6):

Those two comets happen to have large orbital inclinations to the Ecliptic: 117$^\circ$ for
[C/1858 L1 (Donati)](http://www.minorplanetcenter.net/db_search/show_object?utf8=%E2%9C%93&object_id=C%2F1858+L1)
and 162$^\circ$ for
[1P/Halley](http://www.minorplanetcenter.net/db_search/show_object?utf8=%E2%9C%93&object_id=1P).
Long-period comet orbits are oriented essentially at random, suggesting that they originate in the
[Oort cloud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oort_cloud),
a sphere several thousand AU from the Sun.
Many [short-period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet#Orbital_characteristics)
comet orbits are inclined only a few degrees to the Ecliptic,
suggesting origins in the
[scattered disc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scattered_disc),
a torus several tens to a few hundred AU from the Sun.

Comment: The fact that short-period comets tend to have small inclinations (and orbits that are prograde like planets and asteroids) is taken as evidence that they originate from a flattened, rotating distribution: e.g., the Kuiper Belt.

Comment: Noted. The scattered disc seems to be favored over the proper Kuiper belt.

Comment: It seems *the disk* isn't a torus, it's a disk. Instead, *the belt* is the torus: "[The innermost portion of the scattered disc overlaps with a torus-shaped region of orbiting objects traditionally called the Kuiper belt…](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scattered_disc)" 2nd paragraph.

Comment: "...but its outer limits reach much further away from the Sun _and further above and below the ecliptic_"

Comment: OK so is the disk a torus?

Comment: That's how I read it. TNO experts welcome to chime in.